# add confirmation delete bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView

Tags: yii

I want add confirmation delete, how do it?

```
'delete'=>array(
            'class'=>'\ext\crud\actions\DeleteAction',
            'modelName'=>'ManagerCategory',
            array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'),
            'definedAttributes'=>array(
                'id'=>r()->getQuery('id'),
                'store'=>$this->module->getStoreId(),
            )
        )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you are doing this. Here is an example of a confirmation method using a CHtml Button that I use frequently.

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Cancel', array('name'=>'cancel', 'class'=>'button alert large submit','confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to cancel the whole order?')); ?>
```

Comment: I am use bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView

Answer (score 0):

So, right answer is

```
'delete'=>array(
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")',
                    ),
                ),
```

Thanks!

P.S.

```
'list'=>array(
            'class'=>'\ext\crud\actions\ListAction',
            'modelName'=>'ManagerCategory',
            'title'=>'Manage categories',
            'definedAttributes'=>array(
                'store'=>$this->module->getStoreId(),
            ),
            'columns'=>array(
                'id',
                'title',
                'parent'=>array(
                    'name'=>'Parent',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>'$data->parent?$data->parent0->title:""'
                ),
                'delete'=>array(
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
```